# Trying to create a Map but ending with List in JQ

Tags: json, dictionary, jq

I am trying to get the Input JSON given below in the Output Structure given, but i am getting the structure as List instead of Map.

**Input Structure:**

```
{

      "errorMessage": null,
      "errorCode": null,
      "state": "Complete",
       "status": "Completed",
       "createdDate": "234234234234",
       "createdTime": "332432423433",

      "orderId": {
        "Order394": {
          "orderId": "Order394",
          "targetRequirements": [

            { "targetID" : "1234",
            "targetDate" : "targetDate",
              "preferenceOrder": 1,
              "matchID": "502"
            },
            { "targetID" : "1235",
            "targetDate" : "targetDate",
              "preferenceOrder": 1,
              "matchID": "503"
            }
          ],
          "username": "Arun",
          "address": "6166192",
          "Title": "Kumar"
        },
        "Order395": {
          "orderId": "Order395",
          "targetRequirements": [

            { "targetDate" : "targetDate",
           "targetID" : "1234",
              "preferenceOrder": 1,
              "matchID": "502"
            }
          ],
          "username": "Arun",
          "address": "6166192",
          "Title": "Kumar"
        }
      }
    }
```

**Expected Response:**

```
{
      "errorCode": null,
      "errorMessage": null,
      "orderId": {
        "Order394": {
          "orderId": "Order394",
          "targetRequirements": [
            {
              "matchID": "502",
              "preferenceOrder": 1
            },
            {
              "matchID": "503",
              "preferenceOrder": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        "Order395": {
          "orderId": "Order395",
          "targetRequirements": [
            {
              "matchID": "502",
              "preferenceOrder": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

I tried using the JQ Query given below, however this is creating a LIST of orderId, but i need a map.

```
{ errorMessage,errorCode,  orderId :  (.orderId |                               map({    (.orderId) : {   orderId ,          targetRequirements : (.targetRequirements |              map({             preferenceOrder               ,targetID             })            )      }   }) )  }
```

Sample working example can be found at https://jqplay.org/s/exd2QjrS9V

Thanks in advance.
Arunkumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing an invocation of `add`.  Adding `add` to your jq:

```
{ errorMessage,
  errorCode,
  orderId:
    (.orderId
     | map({ (.orderId) :
               { orderId,
                 targetRequirements:
                   (.targetRequirements
                    | map({preferenceOrder,targetID }) ) } })
     | add ) }
```

This yields the structure you want, but the output differs in some details from what you have shown as the expected output, so you will probably want to tweak the filter accordingly.